# 'Spawning.SpawnCube' is a 'field' but a 'method group' was expected

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn a prefab on a set of coordinates in Unity but this keeps coming up.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawning : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject TestCube;
    public GameObject SpawnCube;
    public float CubeFallTime = 7.0f;
    public Vector3 Pos;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnCube());
    }

    IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(CubeFallTime);
        Instantiate(TestCube, new Vector3(0, 6, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SpawnCube is a variable and you are trying to accesses it as a method that why error keeps coming

You should do something like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawning : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject TestCube;
    public GameObject SpawnCube;
    public float CubeFallTime = 7.0f;
    public Vector3 Pos;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Spawn());
    }

    IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(CubeFallTime);
        Instantiate(TestCube, new Vector3(0, 6, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}`
```

It should work fine and please search the internet for this kind of error before posting it as a question on Stack 
Thanks